# Are iPhone/iPod Touch screenshots in landscape mode displayed that way in the app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store, screenshot, landscape

I recently uploaded some screenshots of my app to itunesconnect.  All the screenshots are in landscape mode (I rotated them using iPhoto).  On the itunesconnect page where I uploaded the screenshots they all appeared in landscape mode... fine.  Now on another page in itunesconnect they all appeared in portrait mode (and they were squished).  **How will the images appear in the app store?**  Landscape just like I uploaded them?  or perhaps I need to set something somewhere to let the app store know.

I just want to prevent my app from going live w/ squished screenshots.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to take your screenshots, rotate them 90 degrees, and upload them. Make sure the images are 480 wide by 320 tall, and you should be ok.

See this article for more info:

http://www.appsizematters.com/2010/06/appstore-screenshots-101/

or:

http://thesalon.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-submit-app-to-iphone-app-store.html

In particular, from the latter link,

> Portrait Mode 320x460 Minimum; 320x480 Maximum - 72ppi, RGB, flattened, no trans, High quality jpg or TIFF image file format. Do not include the iPhone status bar.
>
> Landscape Mode 480x300 Minimum; 480x320 Maximum - 72ppi, RGB, flattened, no trans, High quality jpg or TIFF image file format. Do not include the iPhone status bar.

Answer (score 2):

This can be quite a confusing issue because iTunesConnect will show a landscape-oriented iPhone screenshot in landscape orientation, but when you view it from the iPhone app store application, the screenshots will be forced to portrait orientation.

A look at the iTunesConnect Developer Guide, page 13 provides some insight on Apple's reasoning:

> To view a landscape mode screenshot on the device App Store, users will have to rotate their iPhone to view landscape.

So when viewing screenshots on the actual device, iPhones and iPod Touches switch any landscape-mode screenshots to portrait mode and the user must rotate their phone to landscape mode to see the screenshot correctly.

The good news is you can update your screenshots at any time. So do a little trial and error and you'll get it looking good.